# Moving an element back to its original position after animation, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with trying to get this piece of code working properly. I'm moving an element with

```
$("#element").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);
```

Which works just great, but I need to reset it back to the original position before the animation, once the animation is complete so that it will animate again next time.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
        var position = jQuery("#"+that.currentIconSlide).find('.slideInner').position();

        jQuery("#"+that.currentIconSlide).find(".slideInner").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200, function(){
            jQuery(this).css({"left":position.left,"top":position.top}).parent().hide();    
        });
```

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/E4mz9/

Comment: save its position before the animation

Comment: Example of what i'm doing been added, but not working at the moment.

Comment: Could you post an example code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: jsfiddle's read-only, at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#element").animate({'left':'300','opacity':'0'}, 2000, function(){

    $(this).css({'left':'0','opacity':'1'});

});
```

Comment: Cheers for the help,   jQuery("#"+that.currentIconSlide).animate({'right':'300','opacity':'0'},2000, function(){
    $(this).css({'left':'0','opacity':'1'});
});

Comment: Seems to keep kicking out at me this - Uncaught ReferenceError: animate is not defined

Comment: If you're using `jQuery()` instead of `$()` don't forget to change the internal `$(this).css...` to `jQuery(this).css...`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is not use jQuery - I would use plain JavaScript, like this:

```
elem.style.position = "relative";
// animate by adjusting `left` and `top` relative to the start position
elem.style.position = "static"; // jump back to start position.
```

Things are a lot easier in plain JS ;)

Answer (score 0):

just writing code off my mind, might not execute, but you get the idea

```
var position = jQuery("#"+that.currentIconSlide).find('.slideInner').position();

function slide(){
    var original_position = 0;
        jQuery("#"+that.currentIconSlide).find(".slideInner").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200, function(){
            jQuery(this).css({"left":position.left,"top":position.top}).parent().hide(); //? what is this for?
            jQuery(this).css("left":original_position); //set back to original left
            slide(); //run again
        });
}
```